Getting FIS_AUTH_ERROR from FCM (Firebase) in the recreated Android project with the same package name
I have a very old android application and need to update it, so instead of digging in it I've just recreated it with android project anew with the same package name and all. And now when I add FCM and same old google-services.json (I mean, I tried also download json from existing Firebase project, and it's the same) (also, FCM dependencies are updated) the application gets
java.io.IOException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.io.IOException: FIS_AUTH_ERROR

Full exception is:
Fetching FCM registration token failed
                                                                                             

    java.io.IOException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.io.IOException: FIS_AUTH_ERROR
at com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessaging.blockingGetToken(FirebaseMessaging.java:626)
at com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessaging.lambda$getToken$4$com-google-firebase-messaging-FirebaseMessaging(FirebaseMessaging.java:382)
at com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessaging$$ExternalSyntheticLambda10.run(Unknown Source:4)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:462)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:301)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
at com.google.android.gms.common.util.concurrent.zza.run(com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement@@18.3.0:2)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)
                                   Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.io.IOException: FIS_AUTH_ERROR
at com.google.android.gms.tasks.Tasks.zza(com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks@@18.1.0:5)
at com.google.android.gms.tasks.Tasks.await(com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks@@18.1.0:9)
at com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessaging.blockingGetToken(FirebaseMessaging.java:624)
at com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessaging.lambda$getToken$4$com-google-firebase-messaging-FirebaseMessaging(FirebaseMessaging.java:382) 
at com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessaging$$ExternalSyntheticLambda10.run(Unknown Source:4) 
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:462) 
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) 
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:301) 
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167) 
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641) 
at com.google.android.gms.common.util.concurrent.zza.run(com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement@@18.3.0:2) 
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923) 
                                          Caused by: java.io.IOException: FIS_AUTH_ERROR
at com.google.firebase.messaging.GmsRpc.handleResponse(GmsRpc.java:309)
at com.google.firebase.messaging.GmsRpc.lambda$extractResponseWhenComplete$0$com-google-firebase-messaging-GmsRpc(GmsRpc.java:320)
at com.google.firebase.messaging.GmsRpc$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.then(Unknown Source:2)
at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzc.run(com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks@@18.1.0:3)
at androidx.privacysandbox.ads.adservices.adid.AdIdManager$Api33Ext4Impl$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.execute(Unknown Source:0)
at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzd.zzd(com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks@@18.1.0:1)
at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzr.zzb(com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks@@18.1.0:5)
at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzw.zzb(com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks@@18.1.0:3)
at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzc.run(com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks@@18.1.0:8)
at com.google.android.gms.cloudmessaging.zzy.execute(Unknown Source:0)
at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzd.zzd(com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks@@18.1.0:1)
at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzr.zzb(com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks@@18.1.0:5)
at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzw.zzb(com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks@@18.1.0:3)
at com.google.android.gms.tasks.TaskCompletionSource.setResult(com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks@@18.1.0:1)
at com.google.android.gms.cloudmessaging.zzr.zzd(com.google.android.gms:play-services-cloud-messaging@@17.1.0:3)
at com.google.android.gms.cloudmessaging.zzt.zza(com.google.android.gms:play-services-cloud-messaging@@17.1.0:2)
at com.google.android.gms.cloudmessaging.zzk.handleMessage(com.google.android.gms:play-services-cloud-messaging@@17.1.0:14)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7945)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:603)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)

Gadle implemenations:
implementation platform("com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:32.8.1")
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging-ktx'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-ktx'
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-ktx"

I tried to create a new FCM project and added google-services.json from it to application and this works in tests. But to use it in production, it needs to change server part, but still working old application still uses production FCM project.
Does it mean I can't use same FCM project for recreated project?
